# Do we flip the inequality symbol when dividing or multiplying by an expression variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms

> Do we flip the inequality symbol when dividing or multiplying by an expression variable the same way we do when we multiply with or divide by a negative number?

I am currently having some confusion about understanding logarithmic inequalities.

There is one inequality that I’m not sure why I got incorrect.

$$ \log\left(\frac{2x-1}{x-2}\right) / \log2 < 0$$

1. For it to be real, I know that $(2x-1)/(x-2) > 0,$ and so we should be able to cancel out (multiply both sides) the expression variable $(x-2).$
   Without changing the symbol from $>$ to $<$ after multiplication however, I got the result $x > 1/2$ instead of the correct answer $x < 1/2.$
2. I also know that $(2x-1)/x-2 < 2^0,$ and so we should also be able to cancel out the expression variable $(x-2).$
   Without changing the symbol from $<$ to $>$ after multiplication however, I got the result $x < -1$ instead of the correct answer $x > -1.$

After combining both cases in a number line, the correct answer is $-1 < x < 1/2,$

but I got $x < -1, x > 1/2,$ except $x=2,$ which is tested to be incorrect.

I’m not sure if the not switching of symbols is the source of my error, which is why I am asking.

Because this process involves multiplying or dividing expression variables, I also feel that my method is not suitable due to the possibility of extraneous solutions, and maybe should draw and fill in a trial+error table instead.

Thank you in advance for your time and answers.

Comment: you cannot flip the inequality unless and until you're absolutely sure about the nature of the variable(positive/negative, $>1,<1$ etc)

Comment: 1. should be $(2x-1)/(x-2)>1$.

Comment: Thing is, you do not know if $x-2$ is negative or positive. If it is negative, it will flip the inequality sign. The trick is, multiply by $(x-2)^{2}$ instead because square is non negative

Comment: noted, thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\frac{2x-1}{x-2}>0$. Multiplying by $(x-2)^2$ on both sides, we have

$$(2x-1)(x-2) > 0$$

and hence $x < \frac12$ or $x > 2$.

Your mistake is that you have assume that $x-2>0$ must be true.

We also know that $$\frac{2x-1}{x-2}<1$$

If $x>2$, then we have $2x-1 < x-2$, which is equivalent to $x < -1$ which contradicts $x>2$.

If $x < \frac12$, then we have $2x-1 > x-2$ and hence $x > -1$.

The conclusion is $-1 < x < \frac12$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I made a mistake in typing the question, which should be log... <0 and not log... >0, which was why your answer did not match. I have recently edited it. So sorry about that. Nonetheless, I now realized my mistake and got the correct answer.

Comment: I have modified the post according to your edit.